# So I made a file editing program in python... and one of the functions isn't working right

Tags: python, python-2.7

As the title says, I made a file editing program with python.

Here is the code that I'm have a problem with:

```py
#fileEditing.py

def fileError(file):
  raise OSError("file {} does not exist".format(file))

class AccessFile():
  def fileExists(self, file):
    import os
    return bool(os.path.exists(file))

  def filecreate(self, file):
    if not self.fileExists(file):
      with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.close()
    else: raise OSError("file {} already exists".format(file))

  def filedelete(self, file):
    import os
    if self.fileExists(file):
      os.remove(file)
    else: fileError(file)

  def fileread(self, file):
    #check if file exists
    if self.fileExists(file):
      #detect length of file
      with open(file, "r") as f:
        line = " "
        x = 0
        while line != "":
          line = f.readline()
          x += 1
      #piece lines together in a list
      filelines = []
      with open(file, "r") as f:
        for i in range(x - 1):
          filelines.append(str(f.readline()))
      #return a tuple
      return tuple(filelines)
    else: fileError(file)

  def filewrite(self, file, line, text):
    ''' BUG: apparently this either overwrites the line its writing or appends
    to the line its writing... make up your mind!'''
    if self.fileExists(file):
      #get file contents
      filelines = list(self.fileread(file))
      #see if line parameter is out of range or not
      try:
        filelines[line] = text
      except IndexError:
        for i in range(line - len(filelines)):
          filelines.append("")
        filelines.append(str(text) + "\n")
      #apply changes
      with open(file, "w") as f:
        f.write("") #delete contents
      with open(file, "w") as f:
        for l in filelines:
          f.write(l)
    else: fileError(file)

  def fileoverwrite(self, file, data):
    #if there is no file to delete, it will make a new one
    try:
      self.filedelete(file)
    except:
      pass
    self.filecreate(file)
    x = 0
    for line in data:
      print(line)
      self.filewrite(file, x, line)
      x += 1

accessfile = AccessFile()
```

The bug is in the `filewrite(self, file, line, text)` function. When called, it either writes a new line (which is what I want it to do), appends to the line its supposed to replace, or just doesn't write any lines at all.

Say I want to write a python file with this program:

```py
#pytesting.py

from fileEditing import *

file = "/Users/ashton/Desktop/Atom/Python/FileEditing/FileManager.py"
data = [
"from fileEditing import *",
"",
"class FileEditing():",
"  def __init__(options, immutable_files):",
"    self.options, self.immutable_files = options, immutable_files",
"    ",
"  def prompt():",
"    ",
"",
"while True:",
"  pass"
]

accessfile.fileoverwrite(file, data)
```

When I run it, it makes a file with `accessfile.fileoverwrite(file, data)`, like its supposed to.

But thats where things get whacky.

(FileManager.py below)

```py
from fileEditing import *

class FileEditing():
  def __init__(options, immutable_files):    self.options, self.immutable_files = options, immutable_files
    
  def prompt():
    while True:
```

If you know how to fix the `filewrite(self, file, line, text)`, please let me know.

(I use python 2.7 but python 3 is fine)

Comment: You say you have issues with the `fileWrite` function but in your  test code you call `fileoverwrite`?

Comment: could you explain why your `fileread` function is so complicated? why do you open the file twice? and why even count the number of lines, maybe it is something specific to `python2.7` (which you shouldn't use anyways) but still makes no sense and why is your fileoverwrite so complicated?

Comment: @Xnero if you notice then `fileoverwrite` pretty much simply calls `filewrite` multiple times

Comment: @Matiiss I really dont know. im just weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is definitely a Python 3.x solution but you said that it is fine, don't know if it will work in Python 2.x but it is so simple it should:

```py
def file_overwrite(self, file, data):
    with open(file, 'w') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(data))
```

And you seemingly also need to fix that `data` list because it is missing a few commas. Also the fact that this is all in a class is a bit weird, you do nothing with the instance, they all might as well be separate functions or `@classmethods` or `@staticmethods`. Also several things could be improved with your other functions. For example you shouldn't open the file twice and count its lines to read it. Just do `file.readlines()` at it will return a list of all lines:

```py
def fileread(self, file):
    if self.fileExists(file):
        with open(file) as file:
            return file.readlines()
    else: 
        fileError(file)
```

Then also `import os` once at the start of the file, you don't need to import it in every function where you use `os`, also:

```py
with open(file, "w") as f:
    f.close()
```

`f.close()` is completely pointless because the context manger closes the file anyways and also there is mode `"x"` which is specifically made for file creation and will raise an error if the file already exists: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp

Comment: alr ill try it out